# CakePHP DebugKit causes an error

Tags: php, cakephp

I want deploy my project on the server, so I need to disable DebugKit. I removed `CakePlugin::load('DebugKit')` from bootstrap.php and disabled it in AppController.
After that I started getting error 'Fatal error: Class "CakeSession" not found in /vagrant/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php on line 69'. 
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: `zip` your application on localhost and `unzip` that on server...

Answer (score 0):

The error would indicate that your Cake installation is incomplete. Make sure you extracted the entire framework into your document root.

As for the DebugKit, you don't need to remove it explicitly, as it ceases to be loaded once you put the debug level in your app/Config/core.php file to 0 (as live applications should have their debug setting set).

Comment: But CakeSession.php exists in `lib/Cake/Model/Datasource`.
By the way, `Configure::write('debug', 0)` gives same error